# Why is the value for the instruction register 1106 for the load One instruction?

Tags: cpu-architecture, marie

For this question:

Trace the fetch-decode-execute cycle for the following program:

```
1 .org 100

2              Load One

3              JnS IncRoutine

4              Halt

5 IncRoutine , HEX 0

6              Add One

7              JumpI IncRoutine

8 One ,        DEC 1
```

For the load One instruction:

```
  Step           RTL              PC  IR   MAR  MBR  AC  M[103]
Load One   (initial values)       100  -    -    -   -    -
Fetch       MAR←PC                100  -   100   -   -    -
            IR←M[MAR]             100 1106 100   -   -    -
            PC←PC+1               101 1106 100   -   -    -
Decode      MAR←IR[11-0]          101 1106 106   -   -    -
            (Decode IR[15-12])
Get operand MBR←M[MAR]            101 1106 106 0001  -
Execute     AC←MBR                101 1106 106 0001 0001  -
```

I do not understand where the 1106 came about for the instruction register as shown above. If someone could explain that would be great

Comment: For future reference, please tag your questions with the processor / cpu type.

Answer (score 0):

`1106` is the opcode for the `Load One` instruction.  When it starts your trace, it hasn't even fetched the instruction yet.  It loads the program counter into the memory register, then fetches the contents into `IR`.  So, `IR` has "the instruction to be executed".  The next step has to decode the instruction (`1`) and the address field (`106`).

By the way, it would have been somewhat easier if you had given us even the slightest clue where this came from.  This is a fictional instruction set for some fictional computer, but without the details, we're just guessing.